# Using COALESCE when joining multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

In a PG 12 database I have the `reservations` table with the `reserved_between` `tsrange` column.

For a specific `analysis`, I need to know the ending of the last reservation (later in time) and teh following query does just that.

```
SELECT MAX(upper(reservations.reserved_between))
FROM dev.reservations
JOIN dev.analyses ON reservations.analysis_id = analyses.id
JOIN dev.analytical_tests ON analyses.analytical_test_id = analytical_tests.id
WHERE analytical_tests.specification_id = <MYID>
AND analytical_tests.tag = <MYTAG>
```

Where `<MYID>` and `<MYTAG>` are the params needed to identify the analysis.

Now, in case there a no `reservations`, I need to return the  `as_early_as` (`datetime`) value of the `batch` the `analysis` refer to.

I think `COALESCE` could be a good option for the job. Thus, I have updated the quesry as follows.

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(upper(reservations.reserved_between)), batches.as_early_as)
FROM dev.reservations
JOIN dev.analyses ON reservations.analysis_id = analyses.id
JOIN dev.analytical_tests ON analyses.analytical_test_id = analytical_tests.id
JOIN dev.batches ON analyses.batch_id = batches.id
WHERE analytical_tests.specification_id = <MYID>
AND analytical_tests.tag = <MYTAG>
```

However, when I run I get

> ERROR:  column "batches.as_early_as" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1:
>   ...ALESCE(MAX(upper(reservations.reserved_between)), batches.as...

And I'm not sure how to fix it and the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) doesn't help me too much.

What should I change in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(upper(reservations.reserved_between)), MAX(batches.as_early_as))
```